# How to access a date picker in selenium and pytest (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am doing automation testing selenium with python and I got stuck here. I was unable to click on the date. Please help me to get the code to click on the date.

```
enter code here
    #day
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//span[@class='flatpickr-day' and text()='4']")).click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide code and details on what you already tried as well as error message, if there are any. Please also avoid posting screenshots of code/error messages etc. copy-paste those.

Comment: _selenium with python_, why tagging **Java**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the object with needed date, you can do it using XPath:

```
//span[@class="flatpickr-day" and text()="4"]
```

This XPath will select the span with Aug 4 date

Then code this with Selenium/Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-day' and text()='4']")).Click();
```